# retrieving xhtml empty tags via javascript behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, xhtml, tags

I have an xhtml page containing che following snippet

```
<div id="content">
    <br/>
</div>
```

The page has correctly set the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

the problem is: when i use javascript to retrieve the innerHTML of the div element

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML
```

it returns "<br>" instead the expected "<br/>".
Any explanation for this behaviour?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PNekd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers use the Content-Type, not the Doctype declaration, to determine if they should operate in HTML or XHTML mode. If the server says `text/html` then the browser will not be treating the document as XML. The Doctype is only used to switch between Quirks/Standards mode.

In HTML mode, `innerHTML` will give you a serialisation of the DOM to HTML, not to XHTML.